# va_list crash on 64-bits simulator

Tags: ios, nsstring, 64-bit, ios-simulator, exc-bad-access

When using 64bits iOS simulator the init function below crashes with EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1) error. Would anyone know why ? And how to fix it properly.

For information: 'format' is not nil, and it works just fine on 32bits simulator and any 32/64 bits iPhone/iPad devices.

```
void Log (NSString * format, ...)
{
   va_list argList;
   va_start(argList, format);
   NSLogv(format, argList);
   NSString* string = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat: format arguments: argList];
   va_end(argList);

...
}
```

called first thing in AppDelegate

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
   Log(@"app options %@", launchOptions);
   ...
}
```

Comment: Post the entire error message and back trace.

Comment: There is none. It's a bad access so nothing in the debugger and there is no trace in the system log file. It's the first line of the AppDelegate so not so much to feed you.

Comment: Put breakpoint on the line where it crashes, execute `po format` and   `po argList` at debugger console, let us know the what the output is.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Platform inconsistencies with vsprintf and va\_list](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10807310/platform-inconsistencies-with-vsprintf-and-va-list)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Somehow A-Live comment gave me an idea and I found out how to avoid the crash.

I was using argList twice in the same va_start/va_end block

```
[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat: format arguments: argList];
```

and

```
NSLogv(format, argList);
```

It seems that iOS 64-bits simulator don't like it. Don't know why it works just find in any other plateforme (and real devices too). So I fixed it by making two deferent bock like that

```
va_list argList;

va_start(argList, format);
NSString* string = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat: format arguments: argList];
va_end(argList);

va_start(argList, format);
NSLogv(format, argList);
va_end(argList);
```

Hope it will help someone.
If someone knows why, I am still curious to heard about it.

Answer (score 1):

I also just ran into this problem last night. I've filed a Radar for this.

My work around right now is making a va_copy:

```
    NSString *description = nil;
    va_list vaListCopy;

    va_copy(vaListCopy, arguments);

    if (format) {
        description = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:format arguments:vaListCopy];
    }
```

and then later on I call the next method

```
    [[BKAssertRecordHandler currentHandler] recordFailureWithCondition:condition function:function file:file line:line description:format arguments:arguments backtrace:backtrace];
```

In other words, I use the copy locally. 
I've done some experimentation. I made a copy if the va_list and then compared that to the original, after the original was used like so.

```
    description = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:format arguments:arguments];
```

Output during the byte comparison: Mismatch at index 8 (orig=0xd8 copy=0xe0). Prior to the call, I also did the byte compare, and they were the same.

So for whatever reason on the 64-bit simulator, initWithFormat:arguments and NSLogv corrupt the va_list.

Comment: Yes I noticed that the problem came from none constancy of va_list while using in a function, so the copy make sense to. Should work find too.

Comment: is there any solution?

Comment: The solution I'm using is listed above. I opened a Radar on this and Apple did respond wanting some info. But I haven't heard from them in a couple of months. I just tried to run without doing the va_copy using the Xcode 6.0.1 and the problem still exists.

Comment: So I got an email from Apple indicating this is actually considered a coding error. The va_list is already being enumerated, and hence needs to be va_copy before hand if you plan on re-using it. There is also another thread on this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10807310/platform-inconsistencies-with-vsprintf-and-va-list