# C vprintf Modify va_list Argument

Tags: c, printf, variadic-functions

I'm trying to write a function that intermixes calls to `vprintf` with usages of the variadic arguments.  However, the behavior I am observing does not match my expectation.  The following is code that illustrates the problem:

```
static void variadicFunc(int a, ...)
{
    va_list funArgs;
    va_start(funArgs, a);

    printf("a: %d, ", a);
    vprintf("b: %d, ", funArgs);
    int c = va_arg(funArgs, int);
    printf("c: %d\n", c);

    va_end(funArgs);
}

void main()
{
    variadicFunc(1, 2, 3);
}
```

I expected the above code to produce the string *1, 2, 3*, but instead it produces *1, 2, 2* when executing on an ARM64 processor.  Is there some way to get the call to `vprintf` to modify the `funArgs`?

**More Information**:

The goal is to add support for custom format specifiers to a `printf`-like function.  Essentially, I am testing whether the format specifier is one of my custom types, and want to handle that logic myself.  All other format specifiers should go through the default logic.  E.g., if my custom format specifier is *%M*, then my expectation is that the following should be OK:

```
printfWrapper("%0*d%M", 5, 1, /* Args required by the %M specifier */);
```

My expectation was that I could just let the OS format the "%0*d" specifier, which would consume two arguments from the variadic list.  I don't want to have to write code that needs to know how many arguments and of what type I need to advance the list; doing so basically requires me to rewrite the entire functionality of the `printf` function.  There must be some way to accomplish this without needing to rewrite existing functionality, but I can't figure out what that is.  Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I found this post asking nearly the exact same question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10807310/platform-inconsistencies-with-vsprintf-and-va-list.  The answer there indicates it is not possible to do this, and the programmer has to reimplement the standard library functionality.  I added a close vote, but am hoping I am wrong and that Linux provides some standard way to achieve the desired functionality.

Comment: The KISS principle suggests taking a lesson from `strftime()` to do 'extensions' ahead of the call to `printf()`... KISS Or... (sorry for the external link) you could watch this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DYaIgM2XI-E

Comment: C arguments are "call by value."  A copy is passed to the called function, so it can't change the original.

Comment: That's a good idea, but requires a bunch of additional buffers that wouldn't otherwise be required.  If you try to implement that naively, something like `printf("%s%s", strftime(timeA), strftime(timeB));` almost certainly doesn't print what the user expects.  Seems cumbersome to require the user to write code like `char buffA[100], buffB[100]; char *strftime_result =  strftime(timeA); strncpy(buffA, strftime_result, sizeof(buffA) - 1); strftime_result = strftime(timeB); strncpy(buffB, strftime_result, sizeof(buffB) - 1); printf("%s%s", buffA, buffB);`.  Doesn't seem easier to me.

Comment: @Gene On an x86-64 Linux processor, this advances the `va_list` as I expected.  Seems like a concrete counter-example to the statement, "[`printf`] can't change the original [value of the `va_list`]".  The standard doesn't specify the type of `va_list`, so at least that implementation must be passing some sort of pointer so the internal mutations are visible to the caller.

Comment: Some people, eh? Your attempted `strftime()` wasn't quite right... `char bA[100], bB[100]; strftime( bA, sizeof bA, "%y%m%d", timeA ); strftime( bB, sizeof bB, "%y%m%d", timeB ); printf( "%s%s", bA, bB );` (portable...) You can go your own way...

Comment: That's interesting. I guess va_list could be a pointer to buffer that contains a pointer. In that case the called function could update the referenced buffer.  At any rate, you don't get to choose the implementation. I can't see anything in the documentation that requires the behavior you're looking for, so there doesn't seem to be a portable way to make it so.