# Crash on android x86_64 not happening on x86 (Android API30, API31)

Tags: android, c, android-emulator, 32bit-64bit

Former title was: crash on `vsprintf` starting from Android12 (api >= 31)

My Android app uses a native library (libexif) built with NDK. At some time in my native code (adapted from exif), I call the `vsprintf` function which makes the app crash.
Formerly in exif, it was a call to `vfprintf (stderr, format, args);` that I replaced by `vsprintf` so as to store the string for later use.

```c
static void
log_func (ExifLog *log, ExifLogCode code, const char *domain,
          const char *format, va_list args, void *data)
{
  char dest[1024] = {0, };
  vsprintf(dest, format, args);
}
```

The message (as per the output from an API where it works) should be:

```
The tag 'ComponentsConfiguration' contains an invalid number of components (3, expected 4).
```

The `format` variable contains:  "`The tag '%s' contains an invalid number of components (%i, expected %i).`"

I couldn't check the values of the arguments (haven't found how to print them to check their values).

This works without any problems up to API30 (on the emulator).
On an image using API31 it crashes at the call of the `vsprintf` function.

Updating NDK to 25b doesn't fix either.
My API30 image is x86, the API31 image is x86_64.

**Any idea to fix/workaround this?**

Other parts of code that may be of interest:

```
#ifndef NO_VERBOSE_TAG_STRINGS
static void
exif_entry_log (ExifEntry *e, ExifLogCode code, const char *format, ...)
{
    va_list args;
    ExifLog *l = NULL;

    if (e && e->parent && e->parent->parent)
        l = exif_data_get_log (e->parent->parent);
    va_start (args, format);
    exif_logv (l, code, "ExifEntry", format, args);
    va_end (args);
}
#else
#if defined(__STDC_VERSION__) &&  __STDC_VERSION__ >= 199901L
#define exif_entry_log(...) do { } while (0)
#elif defined(__GNUC__)
#define exif_entry_log(x...) do { } while (0)
#else
#define exif_entry_log (void)
#endif
#endif

#define CC(entry,target,v,maxlen)                   \
{                                   \
    if (entry->components != target) {              \
        exif_entry_log (entry, EXIF_LOG_CODE_CORRUPT_DATA,  \
            _("The tag '%s' contains an invalid number of " \
              "components (%i, expected %i)."),     \
            exif_tag_get_name (entry->tag),     \
            (int) entry->components, (int) target);     \
        break;                          \
    }                               \
}

// Then this call later

  CC (e, 4, val, maxlen);
```

#### Update:

- In the meantime since API30 images have x86 arch, and API31 images are x86_64 I just tried API30 with a x86_64. For now:

  - API 30 x86 → **no** crash in app
  - API 30 x86_64 → crash in app
  - API 31 x86_64 → crash in app

So this looks like it is x86 vs x86_64 emulator image related.

- On a real arm8 device, there is no crash either.
- I also found that the args passed to `vsprintf` don't have the expected values. And If a simulate `vsprintf` with the expected values, `vsprintf` works fine. So the problem is likely not `vsprintf`.

Comment: Edit the question to provide a [mre].

Comment: Why are you using `vsprintf()` when you know the size of the target buffer?!?!  Use `vsnprintf()` - and check if you need a larger buffer.

Comment: Thanks for the `vsnprintf` hint. In the meantime I found the problem is not vsprintf but more likely the input data. I replaced "%s" by "%e" and that worked. But the problem is now why is the input bad. @EricPostpischil I'm trying but that's not easy. A simple isolated `vsprintf` with fixed values doesn't fail. Problem is more likely in libexif, or in the source data, or in my code where something has to be changed somewhere. I also have a problem with another C/C++ project I use which also crashes starting from API31...

Comment: @usilo *I replaced "%s" by "%e"*?? `%e` is for a `double` value, while `%s` is for a `char *` value that refers to a `'\0'`-terminated string.  There's no way that "works".  I suspect you're discounting the fact that [`exif_tag_get_name()` can return `NULL`](https://libexif.github.io/internals/exif-tag_8c_source.html#l01122)

Comment: What I meant by "works" is: it doesnt crash, vsprintf works but it crashes because the va_args hold incorrect data. In the meantime I found that with API30 x86: no crash, API30 x86_64: crash. So problem is not related to API but to x86_64 vs x86 ?

Comment: The cause of the problem was that I was using `args` twice. According to https://stackoverflow.com/a/10807375/15401262 it can't be used twice and one has to use va_copy in that case.

Answer (score 0):

The cause of the problem was that I was using `args` twice: Once in `vsprintf` and once in `vsprintf`.

This is now allowed according to https://stackoverflow.com/a/10807375/15401262 and leads to undefined behavior.

It can't be used twice and one has to use va_copy in that case.